# Detect if Meteor serves legacy or modern bundle in production

Tags: meteor

Since Meteor 1.7, Meteor builds a legacy JS bundle to support 'older' browsers and a modern bundle which allows modern browsers to use features like async/await directly, while still maintaining support for older browsers.

Now I'm looking at IE11's Network tab of its debugging tools, and neither from the filename, nor from the response headers I can determine whether the legacy bundle or the modern bundle is served.

I'd expect IE11 to receive the legacy bundle, but how can I detect this?

Comment: Do you need to check it on the Network level or can you use the Javascript console? With Js you can type in the console `window.Meteor.isModern` which returns for me, for example `undefined`

Comment: @Jankapunkt Preferably I'm looking for a method that only requires tooling that's installed on most developer machines. So either JS console or network level is fine, since both are available in basically every browser. If you add your solution as an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In nearly all Browsers are developer tools available and they usually also contain an interactive Javascript console.

You can use it to access the global `Meteor` Object that is attached to `window`. Meteor has a lot of information about connection and the application's status stored in this global.

So you can also access, whether an app is legacy or modern by typing

```
window.Meteor.isModern
```

which will return only true if the bundle is a modern bundle and not a legacy bundle. Note, that this should be used in combination with `window.Meteor.release` to see, if you really expect the modern/legacy feature (it is not supported on older Meteor versions).

Comment: `window.Meteor` seems to be the proper way to access this information. I especially like that it contains a lot of other information that can be handy for troubleshooting Meteor related issues.